# Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined at HTMLImageElement - switch content

Tags: javascript, html

so here is the deal - i'm helping out my friends with their landing page (unfortunately its in polish yet for the sake of reproduction the issue it doesn't matter). So we have this piece of code:

HTML

```
<div class="steps-line-enf text-center">
                <img class="clickable active" src="./static/img/1_krok.png" alt="" num="1 KROK" data="txt 1" />
                <img class="clickable" src="./static/img/2_krok.png" alt="" num="2 KROK" data="txt 2" />
                <img class="clickable" src="./static/img/3_krok.png" alt="" num="3 KROK" data="txt 3" />
                <img class="clickable" src="./static/img/4_krok.png" alt="" num="4 KROK" data="txt 4" />
                <img class="clickable" src="./static/img/5_krok.png" alt="" num="5 KROK" data="txt 5" />
            </div>
            <p class="steps-num-enf brown-text text-center">1 STEP</p>
            <p class="steps-data-enf brown-text text-center">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

JS

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    (function() {
        for (var e = document.querySelectorAll(".steps-line-enf .clickable"), t = function(t) {
                e[t].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    window.clearInterval(o), 5 == (c = t + 1) && (c = 0);
                    for (var n = e.target.parentElement.childNodes, r = 0; r < n.length; r++) n[r].classList.remove("active");
                    var i = e.target.getAttribute("data"),
                        a = e.target.getAttribute("num"),
                        d = document.querySelector(".steps-data-enf");
                    d.classList.add("out"), setTimeout(function() {
                        d.innerHTML = i, d.classList.remove("out")
                    }, 300);
                    var l = document.querySelector(".steps-num-enf");
                    l.classList.add("out"), setTimeout(function() {
                        l.innerHTML = a, l.classList.remove("out"), s()
                    }, 300), e.target.classList.add("active")
                })
            }, n = 0; n < e.length; n++) t(n)
    })(), s(),

        function() {
            var e;
            e = window.innerWidth > 450 ? document.querySelectorAll("#formula-emf .tile-cnt .tile-content") : document.querySelectorAll("#formula-emf .tile-cnt-small .tile-content");
            for (var t = function(t) {
                    e[t].addEventListener("click", function(n) {
                        window.clearInterval(r), 6 == (i = t + 1) && (i = 0), n.stopPropagation();
                        for (var o = 0; o < e.length; o++) e[o].classList.remove("active");
                        var c = n.target.getAttribute("data"),
                            s = document.querySelector(".big-info-emf");
                        s.classList.add("out"), setTimeout(function() {
                            s.innerHTML = c, s.classList.remove("out"), a()
                        }, 300), n.target.classList.add("active")
                    })
                }, n = 0; n < e.length; n++) t(n)
        }(), a()
});
var r, o, i = 1,
    c = 1;

    function s() {
        var e = document.querySelectorAll(".steps-line-enf .clickable");
        o = setInterval(function() {
            for (var t = 0; t < e.length; t++) e[t].classList.remove("active");
            var n = e[c].getAttribute("data"),
                r = e[c].getAttribute("num"),
                o = document.querySelector(".steps-data-enf");
            o.classList.add("out"), setTimeout(function() {
                o.innerHTML = n, o.classList.remove("out")
            }, 300);
            var i = document.querySelector(".steps-num-enf");
            i.classList.add("out"), setTimeout(function() {
                i.innerHTML = r, i.classList.remove("out")
            }, 300), e[c].classList.add("active"), 5 == ++c && (c = 0)
        }, 5e3)
    }

function a() {
    var e;
    e = window.innerWidth > 450 ? document.querySelectorAll("#formula-emf .tile-cnt .tile-content") : document.querySelectorAll("#formula-emf .tile-cnt-small .tile-content"), r = setInterval(function() {
        for (var t = 0; t < e.length; t++) e[t].classList.remove("active");
        var n = e[i].getAttribute("data"),
            r = document.querySelector(".big-info-emf");
        r.classList.add("out"), setTimeout(function() {
            r.innerHTML = n, r.classList.remove("out")
        }, 300), e[i].classList.add("active"), 6 == ++i && (i = 0)
    }, 5e3), window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
        e = window.innerWidth > 450 ? document.querySelectorAll("#formula-emf .tile-cnt .tile-content") : document.querySelectorAll("#formula-emf .tile-cnt-small .tile-content")
    })
}
}]);
```

What's the issue then? so when you will visit the test website:
https://colorfill.pl/dev1/

there will be a section with a headline "JAK PRZYGOTOWAĆ POSIŁEK". If the code would work properly, then after clicking on each icon (washing hands / temperature / spoon, etc) the content (so headline and paragraph) should change accordingly. Yet now - it simply doesn't work. And I have no idea why.

If you want to check how it should work properly, on different website there is a working example: [LINK TO WORKING EXAMPLE](https://www.apteka-melissa.pl/produkt/enfamil-2-premium-mfgm-6-12-mcy-mleko-modyfikowane-w-proszku-4-x-1200-g,41129.html)

I will be more than grateful for any suggestions..

Comment: Was this from some minified code or something? You have function expression assignments in the middle of `for()` conditions, few individual lines (multiple statements separated by commas), single letter variable names. It's very hard to read and follow, let alone debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Patrick said in the comments, this code would be a nightmare to read and find the problem. But luckily most browsers have a console, and sometimes we can figure out some kind of solution (more like a quick and dirty fix) looking at it.

If you click one of the icons and check the console, you will notice that it prints an error, like:

```
main.js:463 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
    at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (main.js:463)
```

The line that it's referring to is this one:

```
for (var n = e.target.parentElement.childNodes, r = 0; r < n.length; r++) n[r].classList.remove("active");
```

So, this `n[r].classList.remove("active")` seems to be the culprit, it looks like sometimes this `n[r]` has a `classList` property, sometimes it doesn't...

If you change the line, checking first if `n[f]` has this property, it works!

```
for (var n = e.target.parentElement.childNodes, r = 0; r < n.length; r++) if (n[r].classList) n[r].classList.remove("active");
```

(i'm keeping it in one line just to change as little as possible from the source)

---

It's important to note that this is just a quick fix, using the feedback from your browser. I actually don't know what most of your code is doing (just have a general idea...). So if you plan on working on this project, you would benefit **A LOT** from putting some effort on making it more legible (future you will be thankful).